# put cursor at end of text in prompt with default value

Tags: javascript, html, web

When calling **window.prompt()** with default value text current is selected,
is there the way to unselect the text and put cursor at end.

```js
prompt("Prompt with default value", "Default")
```

[image]

I also checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt but nothing useful came out.

Comment: No, prompts are pretty much out of your control.

Comment: Why don't you create your own prompt ?, then you will have full control

Comment: @SameerKhan need the quick fix for the solution, just asking is it possible before making one.

Comment: @rho Not possible